# dialog is showing the same result

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

i have this dialog to show the file name when you click on the icon. When i first click it the dialog will be empty then i close it and reopen the dialog will show the name (via ajax). Then when i close the dialog again and click on a different file icon its showing the first file name. then when i close it again and reopen it, it will show the correct filename. Why is it doing this?

Here is my javascript

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var auth = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/edit_filename.php',
        data: {auth:auth},
        success: function(result){
            filename = result;
        }
    });

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      resizable: false,
      title: 'Edit file name',
      buttons: {
          "Close": function() {
              $(this).dialog("destroy");
              $(this).dialog("cancel");
          }
      } 
    });

    $('.ui-dialog-content').html('<input type="text" value="'+filename+'"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i worked out what i did wrong, i was calling the dialog before i got the ajax response

here is the correct javascript incase this happens to you

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var auth = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/edit_filename.php',
            data: {auth:auth},
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                filename = result;
            }
        });
        $.post( "ajax/edit_filename.php", { auth:auth })
           .done(function( data ) {

            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
              modal: true,
              resizable: false,
              title: 'Edit file name',
              buttons: {
                  "Close": function() {
                      $(this).dialog("destroy");
                      $(this).dialog("cancel");
                  }
              } 
            });
            $('.ui-dialog-content').html('<input type="text" value="'+data+'"/>');
        });
    });
```